SE of a product
How can I compute the standard error from this formula below if each variable $X_i$ is the correlation coefficient of samples with a different sample size.
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X_1\cdots X_n) 
&= E[(X_1\cdots X_n)^2]-\left(E[X_1\cdots X_n]\right)^2\\
&= E[X_1^2\cdots X_n^2]-\left(E[X_1]\cdots E[X_n]\right)^2\\
&= E[X_1^2]\cdots E[X_n^2] - (E[X_1])^2\cdots (E[X_n])^2\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\operatorname{var}(X_i)+(E[X_i])^2\right)
- \prod_{i=1}^n \left(E[X_i]\right)^2
\end{align}$$

How do you compute the product of variables with different sample size? What is your point with computing such product?

Assume X1, X2 and X3 are different correlation coefficients and I want to compute the SE of the product of such correlations. However X1, X2 and X3 were measured with different sample sizes: X1=corr(a1, b1), X2=corr(a2,b2) and so on. What would be the SE(X1X2X3)?

I find it hard to conceive of any statistical application where this would be an appropriate or useful calculation.  Would you mind explaining, then, why you want to carry it out?

I need to compute the standard error of the product of pearson correlations. Then I'll plot one pearson correlation against the product of the other 3 pearson correlations. And I need to plot the error bars as well. The thing is that these pearson correlations are not uncorrelated among them, so I cannot use the simplified formula for error propagation: $\sigma_x=|x|\sqrt((\sigma_a/a)^2+(\sigma_b/b)^2+(\sigma_c/c)^2)$

@quantum.girl How is it that the three variables in the product are correlated? Can you describe the correlation and explain how it arrises.

"Then I'll plot one pearson correlation against the product of the other 3 pearson correlations." This explains what you are carrying out, but not why you are doing this. What is the point/interpretation of the product of these three correlation coefficients?

This sounds very much like an xy-problem in the sense that I suspect your product of three correlation coefficients might be a (misguided?) effort to address a completely different question, as yet unstated.  My concern is that even a mathematically correct answer might just carry you further down an erroneous path.  It is out of such concern that I wonder what your actual statistical question might be.

How you derived/obtained the different variables $X_i$ (e.g. a statistic from different samples with different sample sizes) is irrelevant.
The formula only cares about the expectation value $E[X_i]$ and the variance $V(X_i)$ of those variables.
Example, say that the variables are averages of a sample $X_i = \frac{1}{n_i} \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij}$ where $Y_{ij} \sim N(1,1)$ then $X_i \sim N(1,\frac{1}{n_i})$ and $E[X_i] =1$ and $V(X_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_i}}$. These values can be plugged in directly into the formula that you have.

I know that the SD would be sqrt(var(X1X2X3)). But what would SE be in my case? SE is often computed as SD/sqrt(n), I'm not sure what the 'n' is here. Is it 1?

SE is just the estimate of the SD of the sampling distribution of a measured value. Why don't we just use the term SD when it is the same as SE? It is because you can speak about different types of expressions of the error (e.g. an alternative is the mean absolute deviation/error). In the context of errors, and speaking about types of errors, the 'standard error' is one of the specific types.

Basically I needed to compute the SE of this multiplication. You can call it "error propagation" if you prefer.  However the formula that is often given neglects some higher order terms of var(X_i). So you're saying for my case SD=SE?

The formula SD/sqrt(n) is specifically for the mean of a sample. The SD is ambiguous in that formula. In that formula it refers specifically to the standard deviation of a single variable in the sample. E.g. you can write $$SD(\bar{X}) = SD(X_i)/\sqrt{n}$$ The value SD/sqrt(n) is itselve also a standard deviation, namely the standard deviation of the mean $\bar{X}$.

I'm a bit confused. The SE for the Pearson corr coefficient can be computed with the Fisher formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient, but how can I compute a similar metric for the product? SD is way larger than SE (for single correlation). In the end I'd like to plot something like corr(X1,X2,3) as y-axis vs corr(X4) as x-axis. So I'm not sure if SD on the y-axis vs SE on the x-axis are comparable.

@quantum.girl you compute the expectations and variances of the individual correlation coefficients using that Fisher formula that you reference. Then, for the product of multiple of such individual variables youjuse the formula from your question.

Your example with the plot is not clear to me. Where does the product occur?
